# Call Facebook graph API from backend after user connected through mobile app

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, bottle, ionic-framework

i need few advice on my newbie frenchy project...

**How can I call the Facebook graph api directly from a backend (python and bottle) after the user simply gave his authorization on the mobile app (Ionic framework) ?**

I had in mind to send the Facebook token received on mobile app to the backend and use it to access information directly.

Also does anyone know if there is a best practice to get user Facebook information (profile basic info and friends list) on a backend ?

I know my question is very broad, but i'm just looking for a clue to know which way to go

Thank you

Comment: It is explained in the Facebook documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#architecture